# Re-Render Material-Ui's Select Option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, map-function

How can I re render the `<option> </option>` inside material ui select?

What I am trying to do is moving data from 1 object array to the next using material ui select

```
{transferData.map(data => (
   <option key={some key value} value={some value}>
      {data.name}
   </option>
 ))}
```

I console.log transferData where I execute the handler and the console shows that the object array is updating per onClick, but the data is not rendering to the screen. It still shows the initial empty option list.

So I have 3 object array.
Array1 - hold data
Array2 - hold the selected data from material ui select
Array3 - after onClick, move data from array2 to array3

UPDATE*
When transfer data over to array3, the option has this invisible option that I can click on but I don't see the same text as in array1

Comment: The data I got is from the backend database. So I just change data.name to data and it works because only the string data is copy over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're passing some arbitrary values to `key={some key value}`. This could be the issue.

You should be passing any unique value that is related to the array object that it's being mapped to:

```
{transferData.map(data => (
   <option key={data.id} value={data.id}> <--- pass the ID to key
      {data.name}
   </option>
 ))}
```

That way, when the value of `transferData` changes from a blank array `[]` to an array of objects `[{id: 'foo', name: 'Foo'}]`, React understand it has to update the UI.

Please read [the React docs on Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) for more info.

Comment: It is the same key value I use for array1.

Comment: You **must** pass a value related to the array objet, please read the docs I linked, it explains how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, I made [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/override-select-component-material-ui-forked-9oubb?file=/src/index.js) codesandbox example. As you can see, I load data on first `Select` after 5 secs (`setTimeout` on `useEffect`). Data on `Select` will be correctly displayed.

```
// this is the first loading on transferData
const firstRender = useRef(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (firstRender.current) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        let data = [
          { id: 1, name: "name 1" },
          { id: 2, name: "name 2" },
          { id: 3, name: "name 3" },
          { id: 4, name: "name 4" }
        ];
        setTransferData(data);
      }, 5000);
      firstRender.current = false;
    }
  }, []);
```

Then, if you select 1 value from first `Select` I fill the array connected to the second `Select` and also in this case data are displayed.

```
// this is the hadle to fill the secod Select with data selected on first one
const handleChange = (event, object) => {
    let result = [...selectedData];
    result.push(transferData[object.key - 1]);
    setSelectedData(result);
 };
```

The 2 `Select` are like this:

```
return (
    <div>
      <Select
        defaultValue={""}
        onChange={handleChange}
        className={classes.select}
      >
        {transferData.map((data) => (
          <option key={data.id} value={data.id}>
            {data.name}
          </option>
        ))}
      </Select>
      <br />
      <Select defaultValue={""} className={classes.select}>
        {selectedData.map((data) => (
          <option key={data.id} value={data.id}>
            {data.name}
          </option>
        ))}
      </Select>
    </div>
  );
```

Of course this is just an example (if you try to select the same element 2 times from the first `Select` you got an error in console). But in this way, data will be passed from one `Select` to another.

Answer (score 0):

I just change data.name to data, because what being copy to array3 is a string reference to the array1. This work.